# Sql lite Database items not removed permanently

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-sqlite

I made an app using SQL lite database which add some groceries items in database and there are options for updating, adding, viewing and deleting items. All methods are working okay but only until i close the app. i can delete items but on restarting app. they aren't removed.

//DELETE method in Database Handler class

```
public void deleteGrocery(int id){


    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(Constants.TABLE_NAME, Constants.KEY_ID + "=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)});
    db.close();

}
```

The Adapter

```
public  class rvAdapter {

     List<Grocery> groceries;

     public rvAdapter(Context context, List<Grocery> groceries) {


        this.context = context;
        this.groceries = groceries;
    }

// on clicking delete button

        public void onClick(View view) {

            switch (view.getId()){

                case R.id.deleteButton:

                    Grocery g2 = groceries.get(getAdapterPosition());
                    deleteItem(g2.getId());

                    break;
            }
        }
// Delete Item Method


         public void deleteItem(final int id){



            builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.confirmation_dialog, null);

            Button dontDelete = view.findViewById(R.id.noButton);
            Button deleteItem = view.findViewById(R.id.YesButton);

            builder.setView(view);
            dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();

            dontDelete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            deleteItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    // delete item from db
                    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(context);
                    db.deleteGrocery(id);
                    groceries.remove(getAdapterPosition());
                    notifyItemRemoved(getAdapterPosition());
                    dialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
        }
 }
```

Comment: I would check if, those items deleted from the database or not - when you delete them. If you have any cache to store the data fetched from DB before passed to an adapter - is it updated listening to contentObserver.

Comment: Do some basic debugging and check the value returned from the [SQLiteDatabase - delete method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase), as per *"int the number of rows affected if a whereClause is passed in, 0 otherwise. To remove all rows and get a count pass "1" as the whereClause."*.